# New mechanical keyboard not working

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

I've got a new "Kingston KyperX Allow FPS" keyboard, and I have plugged it in, but it's not working

OS: Win7, sp1.

- Media keys work (volume up/down etc)
- changing LED modes work
- caps / num lock doesn't work
- all other typing does not work.

If I plug another keyboard in at the same time (this second keyboard works fine), and if I press capslock on this keyboard the capslock light turns on on the kingston keyboard.

Any ideas? Anyone had anything similar?  or is it just busted...

Thanks

EDIT: Keyboard works in BIOS, but not in windows.

Comment: When you say you plug in a second keyboard at the same time (this works fine), you're talking about the second keyboard right? The Kingston still fails to operate properly? The only basic thing I could think of is to unplug the keyboard, remove the keyboard drivers, and then plug it back in to let it redownload the drivers.

Comment: sounds a lot like its DOA - does it work preboot or in a livecd?

Comment: DrZoo yep second keyboard works, Kingston fails to operate

Comment: Are you sure your connecting the correct USB? One powers/operates the keyboard, the other is just a pass-thru to the USB charging port for power only and is not used by the keyboard itself.

Comment: Yes I have both USB's plugged in, and I tried switching around to different ports.

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to windows using a generic driver to communicate with your keyboard.
Try to find a specific driver for your device, by using the CD given with your keyboard, in case you have one, or using sites like http://www.driverscloud.com to install or upgrade to the latest existing drivers for your machine peripherals.

Comment: There are no downloads or drivers available for this product on official webpage.

Comment: yep no drivers available anywhere that I could find.

Comment: Keyboard didn't come with a CD.

Answer (score 0):

1. Is the Kingston keyboard correctly displayed in Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Devices and Printers?
2. When you're there, you can check the Device Installation Settings. You can turn on installing the best driver from Windows Update.
3. I would also recommend to use [USBDeview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) to check how the keyboard is recognised. It should be green when connected. You can try and uninstall the device and then reconnect.

Comment: 1. under keyboards, I see 4x "HID Keyboard Device" items listed (with both the kingston and my old Dell keyboard plugged in). When I unplug the Kingston, that goes down to 1x.
Strange...
2. and 3.  Will try, but I don't have admin access...